# Ubuntu panel disappear

Tags: graphics

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

After updating found the panel had gone from the screen, searching for the cause found  changing the resolution to 1440x900 panel comes back and working but with 1600x900 it goes out of the screen.
Please help me to restore this to the correct 1600x900 resolution
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`unity --reset`

If that doesn't work, maybe the update didn't complete properly. Try:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you to answer tried  the Unity reset found no changes then did the other suggestion and
no changes after I change the resolution, there is no menu panel on all other applications in 1600x900 resolution.
The terminal print out is to long.